# Use of Sox.exe in c# project

Tags: c#, sox

I made myself a proof of concept to test this tool to manage audio files.My purpose is to change sample rate. My first example works fine!

```
public class Test
{
    public void SoxMethod()
    {
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\sox-14-4-2\\sox.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\sox-14-4-2\\input.wav\" -r 16000 output.wav";
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory= "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\sox-14-4-2";
        using (Process soxProc = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            soxProc.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I want to add this tool in my bin folder but I get the exception: The directory name is invalid

```
public void SoxMethod()
    {
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "bin/sox-14-4-2/sox.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "bin/sox-14-4-2/input.wav -r 16000 output.wav";
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory= "bin/sox-14-4-2";
        using (Process soxProc = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            soxProc.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
```

Maybe its very obvious but I dont know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Try setting working dir to the folder of the executable as so:  `startInfo.WorkingDirectory=AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Comment: First you can Check what is your current directory with Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())

and then you can use Path.Combine with the right path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working directory is wrongly set. Use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` instead. That will make the Process to start at `bin` folder. Then, replace your file and your arguments to work **relative** to the *working directory* (thus remove the `bin` part of your path).

```
public void SoxMethod()
    {
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "sox-14-4-2/sox.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "sox-14-4-2/input.wav -r 16000 output.wav";
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        using (Process soxProc = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            soxProc.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory this is returning debuf folder inside bin

Comment: It will depend on your output build conifguration. Do you have sox-14-4-2 outside of Debug folder?